# Access denied for virtual users.Proftpd

Tags: ubuntu, proftpd

I can't connect to ftp server as virtual user but i can connect as ubuntu user.
I tried set permission for directory 777, 0755, 775 to `/var/www/host` but still get access denied

Here's my config: https://pastebin.com/Y3KWu8up

My virtual user home directory is `/var/www/host`

Answer (score 1):

Usually in your logs you might find more information about this error:

> /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log

But most of them are associated with permissions on your directories, I see that you have tried to change them on your directory but it is still failing
Maybe you can try changing the owner of the directories as a test:

```
chown -R userftp:userftp /var/www/
```

If you want, you can check this [site](https://bobcares.com/blog/proftpd-permission-denied/) where they explain more about it.